# SAS large file download issue

Tags: download, timeout, large-data

I have a SAS application in which we store large chunks of data. We could view, interact and analyze without any issues. However, when I would like to download a particular field that has 200+ columns and about 2 million rows in .csv format, I get the following error message.

> "Table to stream failed with details: initial exception: 'Read timed
> out', converted exception: 'Read timed out'."

If I choose, let's say, a thousand rows, I could download without any issues.
Does anybody have some ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You will need to provide more details to see if this is even a programming question or not.  What type of SAS application? Who created it?  What tools were used to build the application?